# How to resolve error "ORA-00911: invalid character" in Golang?

Tags: sql, oracle, go, bind-variables

I am facing error "ORA-00911: invalid character" while invoking below function. If I use SQL query with hardcoded values (as of now it is commented out in below code snippet) then I am getting db records in JSON response in postman without any issue. So, looks like I am doing something wrong with the arguments. FYI, I am using "github.com/sijms/go-ora/v2" package to connect to oracle db.
Also, 'DashboardRecordsRequest' struct is in datamodel package but I have pasted it in below code snippet for reference.
Please note that as I am doing POC and we will be using stored procedure(s) to interact with oracle.

Postman Request Payload:

```json
{
    "username": "UserABC",
    "startindex": 0,
    "pagesize": 10,
    "sortby": "requestnumber",
    "sortorder": "DESC"
}
```

Go Code:

```golang
type DashboardRecordsRequest struct {
    Username                string `json:"username"`    
    StartIndex              int    `json:"startindex"`
    PageSize                int    `json:"pagesize"`
    SortBy                  string `json:"sortby"`
    SortOrder               string `json:"sortorder"`
}

func GetDashboardActiveRequestRecords(request datamodel.DashboardRecordsRequest) ([]datamodel.ActiveRequestRecord, error) {
    sortby := request.SortBy
    sortorder := request.SortOrder
    startindex := request.StartIndex
    pagesize := request.PageSize
    activerecords := []datamodel.ActiveRequestRecord{}

    slog.Info("Verify values", slog.String("sortby", sortby), slog.String("sortorder", sortorder), slog.Int("startindex", startindex), slog.Int("pagesize", pagesize))

    dbconn, err := getDBConnection()
    if err != nil {
        logger.Error("Could not connect to database")
        return activerecords, err
    }
    stmt, err := dbconn.Prepare("SELECT requestnumber, requeststatus, NVL(requestor, 'N/A'), NVL(pendingwith, 'N/A'), NVL(processtype, 'N/A'), actiondate FROM requests WHERE requeststatus = 'PENDINGAPPROVAL' ORDER BY ? ? OFFSET ? ROWS FETCH NEXT ? ROWS ONLY")
    /*stmt, err := dbconn.Prepare("SELECT requestnumber, requeststatus, NVL(requestor, 'N/A'), NVL(pendingwith, 'N/A'), NVL(processtype, 'N/A'), actiondate FROM requests WHERE requeststatus = 'PENDINGAPPROVAL' ORDER BY requestnumber DESC OFFSET 0 ROWS FETCH NEXT 10 ROWS ONLY")*/
    if err != nil {
        logger.Error("Error while building prepared statement for retrieving dashboard active records", slog.String("Error", err.Error()))
        return activerecords, err
    }
    rows, err := stmt.Query(sortby, sortorder, startindex, pagesize)
    //rows, err := stmt.Query()
    if err != nil {
        logger.Error("Error while executing prepared statement for retrieving dashboard active records", slog.String("Error", err.Error()))
        return activerecords, err
    }
    defer rows.Close()

    for rows.Next() {
        var rec datamodel.ActiveRequestRecord
        err = rows.Scan(&rec.RequestNumber, &rec.RequestStatus, &rec.RequestorName, &rec.PendingWith, &rec.ProcessType, &rec.LastActionDate)
        if err != nil {
            logger.Error("Error while processing database resultset for dashboard active records", slog.String("Error", err.Error()))
            return activerecords, err
        }
        activerecords = append(activerecords, rec)
    }
    return activerecords, err
}
```

Requests Table Structure:

```sql
CREATE TABLE "REQUESTS" (
    "REQUESTNUMBER"          VARCHAR2(64 CHAR) NOT NULL ENABLE,
    "REQUESTSTATUS"          VARCHAR2(128 CHAR) NOT NULL ENABLE,
    "SUBMISSIONDATE"         TIMESTAMP(6),
    "PROCESSTYPE"            VARCHAR2(256 CHAR),
    "SUBMITTER"              VARCHAR2(256 CHAR) NOT NULL ENABLE,
    "REQUESTOR"              VARCHAR2(512 CHAR),
    "PENDINGWITH"            VARCHAR2(512 CHAR),
    "ACTIONDATE"             TIMESTAMP(6),
    "RESUBMISSIONDATE"       TIMESTAMP(6),
    PRIMARY KEY ( "REQUESTNUMBER" ),
    FOREIGN KEY ( "SUBMITTER" )
        REFERENCES "SUBMITTERS" ( "USERNAME" )
)
```

Error:

```
time=2023-10-04T06:43:06.304Z level=INFO source=C:/code/tutorials/myapp/internal/storage/dashboard.go:19 msg="Verify values" sortby=requestnumber sortorder=DESC startindex=0 pagesize=10
time=2023-10-04T06:43:06.603Z level=ERROR source=C:/code/tutorials/myapp/internal/storage/dashboard.go:34 msg="Error while executing prepared statement for retrieving dashboard active records" Error="ORA-00911: invalid character\n"
```

Comment: I don't know Go. You said "looks like I am doing something wrong with the arguments". Oracle complains about "invalid character**\n**. That's a *newline character* (as if you pressed the ENTER key to move to the next line). So: did you do something like that? Pressed ENTER instead of providing parameter value (as if you wanted to provide NULL)?

Comment: @Littlefoot, No, I am not passing anything from terminal or console which can cause press ENTER event. I am making POST call from Postman and sending JSON payload which gets assigned to sql query arguments.

Comment: Could you check that "JSON payload" in editor (such as Notepad++) and set it to *show all characters*? Maybe there's a newline character, somewhere *unexpected*, that causes that problem?

Comment: you have 2 ? in the order by, you need put ',' between them

Comment: Those two bind variables seem intended to be a column name and asc/desc (so no comma needed); but you can't use bind variables for those elements. You could (I think) technically do `order by ?` but that would order by the literal name of the column - i.e. a constant value - and not the value from that column as you might expect.

Comment: @AlexPoole, updated SQL query like 'ORDER BY ?  OFFSET ? ROWS FETCH NEXT ? ROWS ONLY' and then 'rows, err := stmt.Query(sortby, startindex, pagesize)' still facing same error.

Comment: @Littlefoot, In notepad++, with show all characters enabled, just found 'CRLF' in JSON payload taken from postman. No sign of '\n'.

Comment: It looks like you should be using the `:var` bind variable form, not Java's `?` placeholders. There are examples [in this technical article](https://developer.oracle.com/learn/technical-articles/way-to-go-on-oci-article4). And [in the docs](https://github.com/sijms/go-ora#input-parameters) for the package you're using. (What I said before still applies though...)

Comment: @AlexPoole, Yes, you are right. When I raplced 'order by ?' with 'order by :sortby' it worked just fine. Also, as you said ':sortorder' won't work I have to hardcode asc/desc in my query. If I put 'order by :sortby :sortorder' then it fails with error "ORA-01006: bind variable does not exist\n". Can you please add this as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The immediate problem is that you are using the JDBC-style `?` bind placeholders, rather than the expected `:var` form. From the [documentation for the `go-ora` package](https://github.com/sijms/go-ora#input-parameters) you said you are using:

> parameters in oracle should start with : for example :pr1

So your `stmt` should be:

```
SELECT requestnumber, requeststatus, NVL(requestor, 'N/A'), NVL(pendingwith, 'N/A'), NVL(processtype, 'N/A'), actiondate
FROM requests WHERE requeststatus = 'PENDINGAPPROVAL'
ORDER BY :sortby :sortorder OFFSET :startindex ROWS FETCH NEXT :pagesize ROWS ONLY
```

But you can't bind anythng except variables, so it won't allow you to have the `sortorder` as a variable at all, and if you just remove that and do:

```
ORDER BY :sortby OFFSET :startindex ROWS FETCH NEXT :pagesize ROWS ONLY
```

that will appear to work but even that won't quite do what you want, as the ordering will be by the literal column name, not it's value; so it would be run as the equivalent of `ORDER BY 'requestnumber'` rather than `ORDER BY requestnumber`. And ordering by that constant string won't achieve anything.

You would need to embed the ordering criteria in the statement:

```
"... ORDER BY " + sortby + " " + sortorder + " OFFSET :startindex ROWS FETCH NEXT :pagesize ROWS ONLY"
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/JfzVnJ2O) using a PL/SQL dynamic cursor as a simplified equivalent, showing the three versions - one erroring, one not ordering as expected, and finally ordered properly.

But you then also need to sanitise those inputs to protect again SQL injection.

Comment: That extra information again saved lot of time. Now, I have query in a variable like "ORDER BY sortby sortorder OFFSET :startindex ROWS FETCH NEXT :pagesize ROWS ONLY" and I have a reusable function which will check the values of "sortby" and "sortorder" and set default values like "requestnumber" and "asc" if input values are not as expected. These values then repalce the text "sortby" and "sortorder" in the query. Prepared statement will look like "stmt, err := dbconn.Prepare(dbquery)" and "rows, err := stmt.Query(startindex, pagesize)". This might change when we start using stored procs